# Macro to replace print(a) by print(f'{a=}') in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

In Pycharm, I'd like to create a "macro" that replaces a simple print() by a support = fstring print(), that is, when I have a line of code like that :

```
print(a)
```

I would like to replace it by :

```
print(f"{a=}")
```

just by pressing a short cut.

It consists in adding f"{ after the ( of the print and =}" before the ) of the print.

I failed to record such a Pycharm macro.

I also guess they are other ways to automate this task. But I have no clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting there using english keyboard (instead of french keyboard).
It looks like :

[image]